# First-order properties and models of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

It's an open question whether there exists an existential first-order definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ in the language of rings $\mathcal{L}_\text{ring} = (+, \cdot, 0, 1)$, i.e. a formula of the form $t \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow \exists x_1, \ldots, x_n : \phi(t, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ where $\phi$ is a quantor-free formula. Koenigsmann noted in his 2016 article "Defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$" that it might be able to obtain an answer to this question by studying models of the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ and their "rings of integers" (defined by transferring a first-order definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$).

A quick internet search for "models of the rationals" yielded no current research about this topic, although I cannot imagine it has gone unexplored. So my question: what is known about the first-order theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ and have meaningful non-standard models of $\mathbb{Q}$ been constructed/studied?

Some examples (again due to Koenigsmann) of facts about the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ which would lead to results about the original question:

- A necessary condition for $\mathbb{Z}$ to be existentially definable in $\mathbb{Q}$, is that, for any two models $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ of the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$, $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$ implies that $Q_1$ is relatively algebraically closed in $Q_2$.
- A necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathbb{Z}$ to be definable in $\mathbb{Q}$ is that, for any two models $Q_1, Q_2$ of the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ with "rings of integers" $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$ implies $Z_1 \subseteq Z_2$.

Comment: How do you define $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: models relate to theories, not other models, so of course, "models of the rationals" isn't going to turn up anything. Also, what is an existential definition ?

Comment: You are right with your remark, but I tried different wordings (like "model theory rational numbers") and found nothing each time.

Will add definition of "existential definition".

Comment: As a ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is just an infinite rign with one generator. $\mathbb{Q}$ contains infinitely many of those all isomorphic. Which one is the "real" $\mathbb{Z}$? Just the one that contains $1$, the identity of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I consider rings with unity only and do also need 1 as a constant in the language of rings. Will clarify this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What? Even in the language without $1$ named, there is only one subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Maybe you're thinking about groups?

Comment: Though, what is there to study about models of "the theory of Q" (whatever this means) ? :/ :/

Comment: Will add some examples.

Comment: @mercio "The theory of Q" just means the set of all first-order sentences true in Q. It's completely standard in model theory to take a structure you're interested in and look at it's complete theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field which is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ is sometimes called a *Peano field*. Some structural results about these fields are proven in Chapter 4 of the book *Model Theoretic Algebra*, by Jensen and Lenzing.

Comment: But I'm not convinced Peano field is a good name... if I didn't know the definition, I would assume a Peano field was any field obtained by taking a model of Peano arithmetic, adding additive inverses, and taking the field of fractions - as it is, every Peano field is obtained the same way, but from a model of true arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

By the classic back-and-forth argument the following facts characterise $\mathbb{Q}$ as an ordered space:

Let $(X,<)$ be a countable ordered space. If

1. $\forall x \in X: \exists y \in X: y < x$ (no minimum)
2. $\forall x \in X: \exists y \in X: x < y$ (no maximum)
3. $\forall x.y \in X: (x < y) \implies \left( \exists z \in X: (x < z \land z < y)\right)$ dense order.

Then there is an order isomorphism $f: (\mathbb{Q}, <) \to (X,<)$.
So $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\omega$-categorical in the theory of linearly ordered spaces.

Comment: $<$ isn't in the language of rings

Comment: @mercio Maybe the rationals as a ring has a similar characterisation?

Comment: That would be very much of interest to me.

Comment: Though, it is definable thanks to Lagrange's 4 squares theorem.

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: Model theoretically, the rationals as a ring and the rationals as an order are very different, and the ring is much more complicated. The theory of the rationals as an order just says it is dense without endpoints, but the theory of the rationals as a ring contains most of number theory. The theory of the rationals as an order has much more in common with the theory of the *reals* (equivalently, algebraic reals) as a ring—one is the model companion to the theory of linear orders and the other is the model companion to the theory of ordered rings—and that's not what this question is about.

Comment: In other words, the problem isn't that $<$ isn't in the language of rings—it's definable, as you say. The problem is that $+$ and $\times$ aren't in the language of orders.